# Cannot serve static files in webapp with spring

Tags: spring, servlets, web.xml, servlet-3.0

I have a webapp with a very simple web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

I set this contextConfigLocation property so that the class org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.SpringWebApplicationInitializer does not automatically add ContextLoadListener and RequestContextListener as I wish to do this manually.

Then I have my own WebApplicationInitializer class to add servlets programmatically instead of via web.xml.

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SpringWebApplicationInitializer.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
        //Setup spring listeners
        {
            LOGGER.config(LocalizationMessages.REGISTERING_CTX_LOADER_LISTENER());
            sc.addListener(ContextLoaderListener.class);
            sc.addListener(RequestContextListener.class);
        }
        //Jersey Rest Servlet
        {
            final ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = sc.addServlet(ServletContainer.class.getName(), ServletContainer.class);
            registration.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", com.tervita.portal.RestApplication.class.getName());
            registration.addMapping("/rest/*");
        }
        //Normal Servlets
        {
            final ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = sc.addServlet(LoginAction.class.getName(), LoginAction.class);
            registration.addMapping("/LoginAction");
        }
        //Apache Default Servlet
        {
            ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = sc.addServlet("dispatcher", DispatcherServlet.class);
            dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            dispatcher.addMapping("/test");
        }

    }
}
```

When I run my webapp I am unable to access static files I have added such as /css/app/ui-grid.css.

[image: war file structure]

When I run Tomcat I get this though...

[image]

So I am confused I do not have any entries in my servlet config that override the default servlet which in Tomcat should be /*.  Why would the default servlet not be being hit and serve my content?

Comment: in the tomcat admin console, can you see the context (path) your web app got deployed to?  maybe it's deployed to the root context (`/`) instead of `/tervita360` ?

Comment: Yes it is definitely at /tervita360.  Also my test servlet is reachable.

Comment: what about the contents of your WAR file? are they correct? did you look into the WAR file to confirm all the necessary files are in there? - just covering the basics for now

Comment: Yes my .war output looks correct @ochi

Comment: do you have anything mapped to the app root? i.e. `dispatcher.addMapping("/");` ? something like a default/catch-all?

Answer (score 0):

Jersey has a class that implements ServletContainerInitializer called JerseyServletContainerInitializer which was changing my default mappings for /* and such.  I had to disable scanning for ServletContainerInitializer classes in the container via web.xml as per [How to disable Servlet 3.0 scanning and auto loading of components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946487/how-to-disable-servlet-3-0-scanning-and-auto-loading-of-components) and my static resources work again.