# How can I disable Servlet classpath scanning for WebApplicationInitializer classes but still explictly use my own instance?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web.xml, servlet-3.0

As per this question

[How to disable Servlet 3.0 scanning and auto loading of components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36946487/how-to-disable-servlet-3-0-scanning-and-auto-loading-of-components)

I disabled classpath scanning for WebApplicationInitializer classes by setting `metadata-complete="false"` in my web.xml `<web-app>` element as well as adding a tag `<absolute-ordering/>` within my `<web-app>` tag.

Now no instances of WebApplicationInitializer run and it appears WebApplicationInitializer is the only way to programmatically add servlets/filters/listeners instead of in web.xml.

I want to disable all WebApplicationInitializer classes except my own which will have a bunch of entries. How can I configure this?

FYI  I tried adding `<absolute-ordering>` like this

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="false">
    <absolute-ordering>
        <name>com.company.project.MySuperSpecialWebAppInitializer</name>
    </absolute-ordering>
```

But it did not run my WebApplicationInitializer class.

Comment: `WebApplicationInitializer` is a Spring managed class. It only runs because of `SpringServletContainerInitializer`. The servlet container doesn't know anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't metadata-complete="true", instead of "false"?